# Covariance for a gaussian random vector

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, covariance

For a gaussian random vector $X = (X_1, \dots, X_n) \in {\bf R}^n$ with parameters $\Sigma$ and $\mu$, meaning that

$\displaystyle \mathop{\bf P}( (X_1,\dots,X_n) \in S) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2} (\det \Sigma)^{1/2}} \int_S e^{-\frac{1}{2} (x-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu)}\ dx$

for all Borel sets ${S \subset {\bf R}^n}$ (we identify elements of ${{\bf R}^n}$ with column vectors), where $\Sigma = (\sigma_{ij})_{1 \leq i,j\leq n}$ is an $n \times n$ positive definite real symmetric matrix, $\mu \in {\bf R}^n$, show that $\hbox{Cov}(X_i, X_j) = \sigma_{ij}$.

**Question**: If $f: {\bf R}^n \to {\bf R}$ is given by $f(x) = \pi_i(x-\mu)\pi_j(x-\mu)$, where $\pi$ is the coordinate projection function, then by change of variables formula $\hbox{Cov}(X_i, X_j) = \int_{{\bf R}^n} \pi_i(x-\mu)\pi_j(x-\mu)\ d\mu_X(x) = \int_{{\bf R}^n} (x_i-\mu_i)(x_j-\mu_j)\ d\mu_X(x_1, \dots, x_n)$, where $\mu_X$ is the law of $X$. I have some difficulties directly showing this evaluate to $\sigma_{ij}$, in particular when $\mu_X$ is not assumed to be a product measure which split nicely. Any suggestion or hint on things to try will be appreciated.

Comment: What are the definitions you are working with? Under most people's definitions, $\mathrm {Cov}(X_i,X_j) = \sigma_{ij}$ is a tautology.

Comment: @Andrew: It’s not a tautology. Given parameters $\Sigma$ and $\mu$, we define the multivariate normal distribution using those parameters, and aim to show that these parameters can be recovered from the mean and the covariances. See Exercise 29 of https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/275a-notes-2-product-measures-and-independence/comment-page-2/.

Comment: Let $Y=(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)$ be a standard normally distributed random vector. You can show using the change of variables formula that $\mu + \Sigma^\frac 12 Y$ equals $X$ in distribution, then you can go from there.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch: Let $\Sigma = QDQ^T$ be the eigenvalue decomposition of $\Sigma$, where $D = diag(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n)$. If $Y \sim N(0_{{\bf R}^n}, D)$, I did show that $Z = QY + \mu$ is a copy of $X$. Does this substitution work here?

Comment: @YuLynn Yes, that seems fine!

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch: Thank you, I’ll give it a try.